# jquery - remove an image from input type file multiple

Tags: php, jquery

here is a link for js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z7br8/3/

Here is a piece of code

```
function readURL(input) {

if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {

        $('#previewHolder').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}

}
$("#my_file").change(function () {
readURL(this);

});
$('#previewHolder').click(function () {
$(this).remove();
 });
```

The problem is how can i delete a file from multiple input type file when i am removing it from DOM through jquery as you can check it in js fiddle given above. i know input type file is readonly i can not remove it using jquery due to security factors but is there any way to stop that removed file from uploading at submit button. please help me i have to complete this project this month and i am badly stucked at this point.

Comment: You can use the dropzone.js plugin http://www.dropzonejs.com/ . It has  many stuff like multiple file upload ,removing the files ,adding new ones and your backend stuff remains the same .Try it . If theres some problem integrating it ask me .

Comment: i dont want to use plugins can u please tell me another way ?